# How to change element in array by its coordinate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

If I have coordinates of element in array `(|row_index, column_index|)` how can I change the value of element?
This is my array: `element[1,1] == 1`, and I need to change the value of element near it `[1,2]` to `"1"`

```
@data = [
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

That's how I'm finding element == 1

```
@data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |value, column_index|
    if value == 1
      @data[row_index+1][column_index] = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code changes the value under the cell, that contains `1`, but you've stated that you need to change it on the right. I believe your code should be the following:

```
@data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |value, column_index|
    if value == 1
      @data[row_index][column_index + 1] = 1
    end
  end
end
```

You should note, however, since you're changing your array while iterating over it, you'll continue to write `1` to the right, until the elements are done (that will cause an error you get):

```
@data = [
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1], # <-- each iteration will write to the next cell
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

If it's a desired behavior, just check your indexes stay in the array borders:

```
@data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |value, column_index|
    if value == 1 && column_index < row.size - 1
      @data[row_index][column_index + 1] = 1
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise, just break from 2 loops at once:

```
all_done = false
@data.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
  row.each_with_index do |value, column_index|
    if value == 1 && column_index < row.size - 1
      @data[row_index][column_index + 1] = 1
      all_done = true
      break
    end
  end

  break if all_done
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign the value directly by coordinates.

```
irb(main):114:0> a[0][0] = 100
irb(main):115:0> a
=> [[100, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
irb(main):117:0> a[1][2] = 1
irb(main):118:0> a
=> [[100, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Be careful: **element[1,1] is different with element[1][1]**

element[start,length]: returns a subarray starting at the start index and continuing for length elements

element[row][column]: a element of two-dimensional array

Comment: It won't work if array be changed, that's why first I'm finding the coordinate of element == 1 and then change the value of element near it by row or column

Comment: @AzizSharipov you should use element[1][1] , not element[1,1]

Comment: Ye, I'm using it as you told:  if value == 1 (in my case it is [1][1]) then value of [row_index+1][column_index] should change to '1', so I can't do this part

Comment: Added one line to code `@data[row_index+1][column_index] = 1 ` but won't work

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this will be to do something like below:

```
@data = [
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]
]

row = @data.find_index{ |x| x.include? 1 }
col = @data[row].find_index { |x| x == 1 }

@data[row][col.next] = 1
```